# How to draw square pixel by pixel (Python, PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pixel

On blank canvas I want to draw a square, pixel by pixel, using Pillow.

I have tried using img.putpixel((30,60), (155,155,55)) to draw one pixel but it doesn't do anything.

```
from PIL import Image

def newImg():
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1280,768))
    img.save('sqr.png')

    return img

wallpaper = newImg()

wallpaper.show()
```

Comment: Have you looked into `PIL.ImageDraw`? https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html?highlight=shape

Comment: No, I can't use it, it's too complex for my task, it have to draw something on my own, pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running the code you say you have tried totally works, see below.

To draw the rectangle, repeat the `img.putpixel((30,60), (155,155,55))` command with other coordinates.

```
from PIL import Image

def newImg():
    img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))
    img.putpixel((30,60), (155,155,55))
    img.save('sqr.png')

    return img

wallpaper = newImg()
wallpaper.show()
```

sqr.png

[image: black image with a pixel1]

Comment: Thank you! I must have put img.putpixel in wrong place in code.